# Search object by value in array element in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have `updates` in database with this schema

```
{
_id:Number
isRead:[]
}
```

Say I Have these data

```
{
    _id: 1, isRead:[1,2],
    _id:2, isRead:[3,4],
    _id:3, isRead:[1]
}
```

when i use this query

`updates.find('isRead':1)` in mongo db it returns the needed result which is the first and the last
But in mongoose i use the same query but it doesn't return any data,
How can I modify my query in mongoose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put the type in the schema

```
isRead[Number]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
updates.find(isRead:{$in:[1]})
```

for $in refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: It's the same, the $in operator like this is the same with 'isRead:1'

Comment: No this is not same when you do query on array field you use $in operator.